# close() vs. shutdown() with recv()

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I have the following code:

Client side:

```
n=recv(sock,buf,1200,NULL);
```

Server side:

```
shutdown(sockk,SD_BOTH);
```

The problem is, the client side `recv` is returning 0, meaning graceful shutdown. I need it to return -1 (I can't change the client side, I need to adapt my code to it.)

What can i do to cause it returning -1?

Comment: Why should it return -1? this is a graceful shutdown.
If you don't want a graceful shutdown, don't use `shutdown()`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
Set the socket with `SO_LINGER` and thus cause an abortive shutdown.
Now it returns `-1` after `shutdown()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call shutdown() or close() from server, and you can then send some signal to the client side process. So recv() call will return -1 with errno set with EINTR. Hope this helps.

But I suggest you should not adopt such coding practice. recv() can return 0, +ve number and -1. Its good to handle all these cases.